# Alignment menu with logo and search box

Tags: html, css

I have a problem editing the following menu. I don´t know what I'm doing wrong.

```css
.page_menu_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.clear {
    clear:both
}

.page-menu ul li { 
    list-style:none;
}
.page-menu ul li { 
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
    transition:all 400ms ease-in-out}

.page-menu {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:0!important;
    margin:0 5px;
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:400}

.page-menu ul {
    margin:0 auto!important;
    text-align:center; 
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    padding:0!important;
    line-height:3em}

.page-menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #00f;
    color:#e8554e!important}

.page-menu ul li a {
    color:white!important;
    padding:0 40px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.page-menu ul li a img {
    vertical-align:middle!important}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
.page-menu,.search-box {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 }
    
.page-menu ul li {
    width:33.3%;
    float:left}
    
.page-menu ul li:first-child {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top:10px}
    
.page-menu ul li:last-child {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;}
    
.page-menu ul li {
    text-align:center}
    
.page-menu ul li a {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0}

.page_menu_wrapper {
    padding-bottom:10px}
    
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    .page-menu ul {line-height:2em}
}

@media screen and (max-width:240px){
.page-menu ul li{width:50%}
}

.searchform {
 display: inline-block;
 zoom: 1; /* ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
 *display: inline;
 border: solid 1px #d2d2d2;
 padding: 3px 5px;}
.searchform input {
 font: normal 12px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.searchform .searchfield {
 background: #fff;
 padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;
 width: 202px;
 border: solid 1px #bcbbbb;
 outline: none;

 -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
 -moz-border-radius: 2em;
 border-radius: 2em;

 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);}

.searchform .searchbutton {
 color: #fff;
 border: solid 1px #494949;
 font-size: 11px;
 height: 27px;
 width: 27px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

 -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
 -moz-border-radius: 2em;
 border-radius: 2em;

 background: #5f5f5f;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#9e9e9e), to(#454545));
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9e9e9e,  #454545);
 filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545'); /* ie7 */
 -ms-filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545'); /* ie8 */
}
```

```html
<div class="page_menu_wrapper">
<nav class='page-menu'>
 <ul>
   <li><a href='/'><img height='70' src='http://xf.com/new/logo.png' width='171'/></a></li>
   <li><a href='about.php'><span itemprop='name'>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='contact.php'><span itemprop='name'>Contact</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='privacy.php'><span itemprop='name'>Privacy</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='sitemap.php'><span itemprop='name'>Sitemap</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='iklan.php'><span itemprop='name'>Iklan</span></a></li>
   <li><form class="searchform">
 <input class="searchfield" type="text" value="Search..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" />
 <input class="searchbutton" type="button" value="Go" />
</form></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>

    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

The logo is not on the left and search box on the right.

Lines are not the same height (see green color). Links do not have the same height and width of the cell. The effect of mouse click on the link (blue color) is not across the cell.

I found a similar menu but is not responsive. See https://jsfiddle.net/mr5Ljfm5/

Please can you help me to adjust the following menu?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox to help with vertical alignment and spacing between items.

```css
.page_menu_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
}

.page-menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: green;
}

.page-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.page-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.page-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #00f;
  color: #e8554e;
}

.page-menu ul li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 40px 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  .page-menu,
  .search-box {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0
  }
  .page-menu ul li {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left
  }
  .page-menu ul li:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 10px
  }
  .page-menu ul li:last-child {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .page-menu ul li {
    text-align: center
  }
  .page-menu ul li a {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0
  }
  .page_menu_wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 10px
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .page-menu ul {
    line-height: 2em
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:240px) {
  .page-menu ul li {
    width: 50%
  }
}

.searchform {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  /* ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
  *display: inline;
  border: solid 1px #d2d2d2;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.searchform input {
  font: normal 12px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.searchform .searchfield {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;
  width: 202px;
  border: solid 1px #bcbbbb;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
  -moz-border-radius: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.searchform .searchbutton {
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #494949;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
  -moz-border-radius: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #5f5f5f;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#9e9e9e), to(#454545));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9e9e9e, #454545);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545');
  /* ie7 */
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545');
  /* ie8 */
}
```

```html
<div class="page_menu_wrapper">
  <nav class='page-menu'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href='/'><img height='70' src='http://xf.com/new/logo.png' width='171' /></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='about.php'><span itemprop='name'>About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='contact.php'><span itemprop='name'>Contact</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='privacy.php'><span itemprop='name'>Privacy</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='sitemap.php'><span itemprop='name'>Sitemap</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='iklan.php'><span itemprop='name'>Iklan</span></a></li>
      <li>
        <form class="searchform">
          <input class="searchfield" type="text" value="Search..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" />
          <input class="searchbutton" type="button" value="Go" />
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use a flex, then the responsive menu does not work :( What do I need to change in the code when I need the blue color to reach the link across the cell height and width?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    //add responsive class for mobile view
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mytopmenu");
    if (x.className === "topmenu") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topmenu";
    }
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;}

.topmenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:black;
}

.topmenu .icon {
  display: none;
}
.topmenu a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.topmenu a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}


/* styles for mobile view*/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /*removes links except for first child*/
  .topmenu a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topmenu a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .topmenu.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topmenu.responsive .icon {
      /*fixing top right menu icon*/
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topmenu.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
.content{
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topmenu" id="mytopmenu">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">Privacy</a>
  <a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>your website content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to change colors and replace first menu item with your logo.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you:

```css
.page_menu_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.clear {
    clear:both
}

.page-menu ul { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.page-menu ul li { 
    float: left;
    padding: 0 7px;
    background-color:green;
    transition:all 400ms ease-in-out}

.page-menu {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:0!important;
    margin:0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:400}

.page-menu ul {
    margin:0 auto!important;
    text-align:center; 
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    padding:0!important;
    line-height:72px}

.page-menu li a:hover {
    
    background-color:#e8554e!important}

.page-menu ul li a {
    color:white!important;
    padding:0 40px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.page-menu ul li a img {
    vertical-align:middle!important}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
.page-menu,.search-box {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 }
    
.page-menu ul li {
    width:33.3%;
    float:left}
    
.page-menu ul li:first-child {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top:10px}
    
.page-menu ul li:last-child {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;}
    
.page-menu ul li {
    text-align:center}
    
.page-menu ul li a {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0}

.page_menu_wrapper {
    padding-bottom:10px}
    
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    .page-menu ul {line-height:2em}
}

@media screen and (max-width:240px){
.page-menu ul li{width:50%}
}

.searchform {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
    *display: inline;
    padding:0 5px;}
.searchform input {
    font: normal 12px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.searchform .searchfield {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;
    width: 202px;
    border: solid 1px #bcbbbb;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);}

.searchform .searchbutton {
    color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #494949;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 27px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;

    background: #5f5f5f;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#9e9e9e), to(#454545));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9e9e9e,  #454545);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545'); /* ie7 */
    -ms-filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545'); /* ie8 */
}
```

```html
<div class="page_menu_wrapper">
<nav class='page-menu'>
 <ul>
   <li><a href='/'><img height='70' src='logo.png' width='171'/></a></li>
   <li><a href='about.php'><span itemprop='name'>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='contact.php'><span itemprop='name'>Contact</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='privacy.php'><span itemprop='name'>Privacy</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='sitemap.php'><span itemprop='name'>Sitemap</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='iklan.php'><span itemprop='name'>Iklan</span></a></li>
   <li><form class="searchform">
 <input class="searchfield" type="text" value="Search..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" />
 <input class="searchbutton" type="button" value="Go" />
</form></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>

    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks good, but the search box on the smaller screen is on the same line as the link. What do I need to change in the code when I need the pink color to reach the link across the cell height and width? It now appears only in the word size. Would it make the logo on the right side of the page border and the search box on the left side of the page border?